# Why do I get unable to import module when creating a custom AWS Lambda Layer for Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a module called `custom_module.py` which has functions and methods that I would like to use across a few different Lambdas. The code looks like this:

```
def test():
    return 'Custom module'
```

I tried to convert this into a Lambda Layer by zipping up this file and using the form to create a layer. Everything seemed to work nicely, and I imported the module into my Lambda for use, like so:

```
import json
from custom_module import test

print('Loading function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return test()
```

Unfortunately, running this returns a `"Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'custom_module'"` error. What exactly am I doing wrong here? I have the correct runtimes and architecture specified as well.

**Edit**

Going by the comment, I tried this file structure:

```
layer
|
+--- python
     |
     +--- custom_module
          |
          +--- __init__.py (contains the test() method)
```

I zipped up the `layer` folder as `layer.zip` and uploaded it. Still get the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Did you configure the Lambda function to use the layer? Did you correctly package the layer code in a subfolder named `python`?

Comment: @jarmod Tried that, details in the new edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path), for Python runtimes, **the Lambda layer should only have 1 subfolder called `python`** so that the Lambda can access the layer content without the need to specify the path (or it needs to be a site package within `python/lib/python3.9/site-packages`).

You have 2 subfolders - `layer` and then `python`.

**Change your file structure to have your `custom_module` inside the `python` folder only.**

```
layer.zip
|
+--- python
     |
     +--- custom_module
          |
          +--- __init__.py (contains the test() method)
```